# Compiling code with TCP_REPAIR socket option on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu

Following this article, I am trying to get a C program to compile that uses TPC_REPAIR.

http://oroboro.com/dealing-with-network-port-abuse-in-sockets-in-c/

TCP_REPAIR is defined in

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h
```

Including this header conflicts with the ones required for other socket APIs.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <uapi/linux/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int cfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char ch='r';
    cfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.160.102.40");
    addr.sin_port=htons(9988);
    if(connect(cfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,
    sizeof(addr))<0) {
        perror("connect error");
        return -1;
    }
    if(write(cfd, &ch, 1)<0) perror("write");
    if(read(cfd, &ch, 1)<0) perror("read");
    printf("\nReply from Server: %c\n",ch);
    //close(cfd);

    int aux = 1;
    if(setsockopt(cfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_REPAIR, &aux, sizeof( aux )) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "could not turn on repair mode" );
    }
   return 0;
}
```

And here's gcc output

```
In file included from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:56:0,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:45:18: error: conflicting types for ‘loff_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:45:26: note: previous declaration of ‘loff_t’ was here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:61:17: error: conflicting types for ‘dev_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:15:25: note: previous declaration of ‘dev_t’ was here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:76:19: error: conflicting types for ‘nlink_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:19:17: note: previous declaration of ‘nlink_t’ was here
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:133:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:56,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/time.h:104:19: error: conflicting types for ‘timer_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:25:26: note: previous declaration of ‘timer_t’ was here
In file included from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:56:0,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:198:1: error: conflicting types for ‘int64_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:113:17: note: previous declaration of ‘int64_t’ was here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:204:1: error: conflicting types for ‘u_int64_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:112:17: note: previous declaration of ‘u_int64_t’ was here
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:220:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:56,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:76:5: error: conflicting types for ‘fd_set’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:14:26: note: previous declaration of ‘fd_set’ was here
In file included from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:56:0,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:236:20: error: conflicting types for ‘blkcnt_t’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/types.h:134:23: note: previous declaration of ‘blkcnt_t’ was here
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/uio.h:29:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:57,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/uio.h:44:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct iovec’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/uapi/linux/uio.h:16:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:57,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:180:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sockaddr’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/uapi/linux/socket.h:19:27: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:193:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct __kernel_sockaddr_storage’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/uapi/linux/socket.h:13:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:204:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:253:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct msghdr’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/socket.h:47:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:280:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct cmsghdr’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/socket.h:69:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:310:24: error: conflicting types for ‘__cmsg_nxthdr’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/socket.h:111:32: note: previous definition of ‘__cmsg_nxthdr’ was here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:339:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:57,
                 from new_client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:417:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct linger’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/socket.h:34:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from new_client.c:6:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:24:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct tcphdr’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:92:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:135:6: error: nested redefinition of ‘enum tcp_ca_state’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:135:6: error: redeclaration of ‘enum tcp_ca_state’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:179:6: note: originally defined here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:136:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TCP_CA_Open’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:181:3: note: previous definition of ‘TCP_CA_Open’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:138:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TCP_CA_Disorder’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:182:3: note: previous definition of ‘TCP_CA_Disorder’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:140:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TCP_CA_CWR’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:183:3: note: previous definition of ‘TCP_CA_CWR’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:142:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TCP_CA_Recovery’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:184:3: note: previous definition of ‘TCP_CA_Recovery’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:144:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘TCP_CA_Loss’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:185:3: note: previous definition of ‘TCP_CA_Loss’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:148:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct tcp_info’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:188:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h:193:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct tcp_md5sig’
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:235:8: note: originally defined here
```

Comment: You should make friends with someone you trust to goof around on your system.  We aren't you and we don't have your kernel headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really not useful

```
#include "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h"
```

Because either the kernel supports it or it does not.   You can check for it like this:

```
find /usr/include -type f -exec grep TCP_REPAIR {} /dev/null \;
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:#define TCP_REPAIR     19  /* TCP sock is under repair right now */
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:#define TCP_REPAIR_QUEUE   20
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:#define TCP_REPAIR_OPTIONS 22
```

if it's there, great, otherwise you'll have to use the workaround.

Here's an Ubuntu that has it

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal
```

It looks like SOL_TCP is only defined in /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h

```
find /usr/include -type f -exec grep SOL_TCP {} /dev/null \;
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:# define SOL_TCP     6   /* TCP level */
```

To overcome the unfortunate absence of SOL_TCP in /usr/include/linux/tcp.h.  You can try to simply copy it from netinet/tcp.h, it's just a number after all.

```
#ifndef SOL_TCP
#define SOL_TCP 6
#endif
```

However, the man page of setsockopt offers an even better approach:

> To manipulate options at any other level the protocol number of the appropriate protocol controlling the option is supplied.  For example, to indicate that an option is to be interpreted by the TCP protocol, level should be set to the protocol number of TCP; see getprotoent(3).

Comment: Upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and now I see TCP_REPAIR in the right place (/usr/include/linux/tcp.h). Thanks.

Comment: When I included linux/tcp.h, it conflicted with netinet/tcp.h. When I removed netinet/tcp.h, compiler cannot find SOL_TCP.  Any tips?

Comment: Yea, that's a bummer, I've updated the answer with a couple of suggestions

Comment: Got it, after adding the define I have working code now!